# When i am creating Web Application project in Eclipse for creating user account using Provisioning API i am getting the following errors

Tags: java, gwt

```
[DEBUG] [createuser] - Validating newly compiled units
    [ERROR] [createuser] - Errors in 'file:/D:/Neha_workspace/CreateUser/src/com/shared/AppsForYourDomainClient.java'
        [ERROR] [createuser] - Line 324: No source code is available for type java.net.URL; did you forget to inherit a required module?
        [ERROR] [createuser] - Line 1059: The method exit(int) is undefined for the type System
    [ERROR] [createuser] - Errors in 'file:/D:/Neha_workspace/CreateUser/src/com/shared/api/gbase/client/AttributeHistogram.java'
        [ERROR] [createuser] - Line 340: No source code is available for type org.xml.sax.Attributes; did you forget to inherit a required module?
    [ERROR] [createuser] - Errors in 'file:/D:/Neha_workspace/CreateUser/src/com/shared/api/gbase/client/ConversionUtil.java'
        [ERROR] [createuser] - Line 239: No source code is available for type com.google.common.collect.Multimap<K,V>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
    [ERROR] [createuser] - Errors in 'file:/D:/Neha_workspace/CreateUser/src/com/shared/api/gbase/client/FeedURLFactory.java'
        [ERROR] [createuser] - Line 35: No source code is available for type java.net.URL; did you forget to inherit a required module?
        [ERROR] [createuser] - Line 75: No source code is available for type java.net.MalformedURLException; did you forget to inherit a required module?
        [ERROR] [createuser] - Line 117: No source code is available for type java.net.URLEncoder; did you forget to inherit a required module?
    [ERROR] [createuser] - Errors in 'file:/D:/Neha_workspace/CreateUser/src/com/shared/api/gbase/client/GmAttributes.java'
        [ERROR] [createuser] - Line 142: No source code is available for type org.xml.sax.Attributes; did you forget to inherit a required module?
    [ERROR] [createuser] - Errors in 'file:/D:/Neha_workspace/CreateUser/src/com/shared/api/gbase/client/GmDisapproved.java'
        [ERROR] [createuser] - Line 59: No source code is available for type org.xml.sax.Attributes; did you forget to inherit a required module?
    [ERROR] [createuser] - Errors in 'file:/D:/Neha_workspace/CreateUser/src/com/shared/api/gbase/client/GmPublishingPriority.java'
        [ERROR] [createuser] - Line 122: No source code is available for type org.xml.sax.Attributes; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Comment: Did you forget to inherit a required module?

Comment: You need to add more details here

Answer (score 1):

You've used classes that aren't supported on the GWT client's side. You should move them to server side (GWT RPC servlets for example) and call them from client code using async callbacks.
Classes that can be used on the client's side of GWT are listed here: http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/webtoolkit/doc/2.2/RefJreEmulation.html.